# Filter nested objects in a list in Flutter and get the values of filtered object

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List of objects which I want to filter and get the value of a key based on the filtered list.

```
 class CategoryData({
    String name,
    List<SubCategoryData> subCategories
  })


  const SubCategoryData({
    required String name,
    required String id,
 })
```

The data might look like this, I want to get the object for a matching key value:

```
  final list =  [{
        "categoryData": {
            "name": "Test123",
            "subCategories": [{
                "name": "Test123",
                "id": "Testid"
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "categoryData": {
            "name": "Test456",
            "subCategories": [{
                "name": "**Test456**", //Get name for matching id below
                "id": "*Testid456*"
            }]
        }
    }
    ]
```

I want to get the value of the "name" key for matching "id" of subCategories

i.e, I want to get "Test456" for matching "Testid456".

I have tried following but it gives me the whole parent list which is not very helpful.

```
final getFilteredList = list
        .where((content) =>
            content.subCategories.any((tag) => tag.id == 'Testid456'))
        .toList();
```

Comment: Your current approach would give you a `List<CategoryData>` where you have `SubCategoryData` that matches the id. I'm not entirely sure what you want instead. Do you want a list of just the `SubCategoryData` which have a matching id, or do you want a list of strings with just the corresponding name, or something else?

Comment: @mmcdon20, I want the list of Strings of "name" key for a matching "id" value in the subCategories. 

A method which takes the List<CategoryData> and return the List<Strings> which has "name" for a given id

Comment: I would do something along the lines of this:   `[ for (final category in categoryData) for (final subCategory in category.subCategories) if (subCategory.id == 'Testid456') subCategory.name ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
String result = searchFromId(searchId, categoryDataList);
print(res);
```

```
String searchFromId(String searchId, List<CategoryData> catDataList) {
  return catDataList
      .where((e) =>
          e.subCatData
              .firstWhere((d) => d.id == searchId,
                  orElse: () => SubCategoryData("", ""))
              .id !=
          "")
      .first
      .name;
}
```

If you want to have a list of names use .map() along with .where(). Like below

```
List<String> searchFromId(String searchId, List<CategoryData> catDataList) {
  return catDataList
      .where((e) =>
          e.subCatData
              .firstWhere((d) => d.id == searchId,
                  orElse: () => SubCategoryData("", ""))
              .id !=
          "").map((e)=>e.name).toList();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. This one gives the String value of the parent object 'name', from my example it returns "Test456". What changes do I have to do to get string value for 'name' of same object("**Test456**")

Comment: To do so, change `catDataList.where(<filter_to_search_sub_category>)` with `catDataList.map(<filter_to_search_sub_category>).toList()` and then on its result, you need add one more filter like `.where((res) => res.isNotEmpty).toList()` and get the first item of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in dart.  convert python to dart

```
name="Test456"
for x in data:
    if x['categoryData']['name'] == name:
        print(x)
```